# How to inner join two tables using Hibernate HQL or Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

```
@Entity
public class doctor {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private String phone;
   private String email;

   @OneToMany(targetEntity = patient.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
   @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
   private Collection<patient> patients = new ArrayList<patient>();
}

@Entity
public class patient {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String phone;
   private int systolic;
   private int diastolic;

   @ManyToOne
   private doctor doctor;
}
```

For now i can retreive only doctors information by this criteria:

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(doctor.class);
query.createCriteria("patients", "p");
query.add(Restrictions.eq("p.phone", phone));
List<doctor> doctorList = (ArrayList<doctor>) query.list();
```

How i can with hibernate criteria retreive by giving patient phone, his doctor information and some patients information?

> Something like : phone=3423423424 , then answear is :
>
> -------------doctor's info----------------------------------patientinfo(systolic,diastolic)-----------------------

```
  1 "Dr dre" sdfssd 243242 drdre@gmail.com  160 170
```

where `160 170` are the patient's information

If not with criteria, with HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bidirectional mapping so from each doctor you can get his patients and from each patient you can get his doctor information. If you need a list with patients instead a list of doctors just create analogous Criteria for patients. `session.createCriteria(patient.class)`, with needed restrictions. you don't have to make it eager. In most cases we don't need eager fetching. It is much better initialize (Hibernate.initialize) the collection or proxy if you would need the objects outside the hibernate session.

btw use camel case when you name java classes. It's widely used convention.

Comment: every patient has one doctor.So i want the doctor info where his patient phone is "45353534" + the patient info.Can this be done?            [Doctor.phone Doctor.email Patient.diastolic Patient.Systolic]

Comment: of course that can be done. create criteria for patient class as I wrote above with restrictions for specific phone number. then you will get a list of patients that have this specific phone number. then you can iterate through this list and for each patient get his doctor. if you would to it in hibernate session you don't have to have initialized proxy. when you will get doctor from patient by patient.getDoctor() you have of course all properties of doctor available. it's java and these are objects! the only trick here is to remember initialize proxies.

Comment: read a bit about java and objects, and look at hibernate documentation. these are objects, if you want such information in a string, you have iterate through object model and create a string from objects properties by yourself in java code.

Comment: So with the criteria query i used above i can retreive doctor info.To retreive his particular patient, i will do:                         for (doctor d : doctorList) {answear = answear.concat(d.getPhone()+ " " + d.getEmail()+" "+d.getPatient().diastolic+" ?"+d.getPatient().systolic);}

Comment: almost. to prefilter patients to only these that have selected number you can use left outer join like this:  Criteria query = session.createCriteria(doctor.class);
    query.createCriteria("patients", "p", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("p.phone", phone)); then you will get doctors with only these patients that have the restricted phone number

Comment: if you can assume that each doctro has only one patient with selected phone number then you can do d.getPhone +...+d.getEmail+...+d.getPatients().get(0).diastolic etc. (remember that one doctor has a list of patients, so potentially can have one with the same phone number

Comment: I solved it using instead of get(0).getSystolic --> iterator.next.getSystolic! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the following.

With Hibernate Criteria API:

```
Criteria query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
createCriteria(Patient.class, "patient");
query.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().
add(Projections.property("patient.doctor")).
add(Projections.property("patient.systolic")).
add(Projections.property("patient.diastolic")));
query.add(Restrictions.eq("patient.phone", phone));
return query.list();
```

With HQL (actually just JPQL):

```
select p.doctor, p.systolic, p.diastolic from Patient p where p.phone = ?1
```

What you get in the result is value of Type `List<Object[]>`. 
Also add `@Cascade(value=CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)` to `doctor` field on your `Patient` class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your query only returns the doctors information (and not the patient's information) is because [for a OneToMany relation, FetchType by default is set to LAZY](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html), if you specify fetch type to be EAGER, hibernate will also return patients.

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = patient.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: How is done that?I have the doctorList .How to retreive both patient and doctor info.I want to pass them to a string."doctor phone is " +doctor.phone + ... + "patient diastolic is " patient.diastolic +...

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using HibernateTemplate

```
String hql = "from Boo where id in (:listParam)";
String[] params = { "listParam" };
Object[] values = { list};
List boos = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(hql, params, values);
```

Quoted from [Spring Forum](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-29104.html)